# How to render Backbone.js view AFTER jQuery document ready has fired?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, document-ready

I have a simple Backbone.js page where in the view I am getting a div from the DOM and adding another div to it....

```
<body>
<div id="starbase"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#starbase"), 

        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
            this.render(); 
        },
        render: function(){
            $(this.el).append('<div id="starship"></div>');
        }
    });

    var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
```

Is there any way I can force this render function to fire after jQuery DOM ready event has happened? Meaning the starship div should only get added to the starbase div after the jQuery ready has already happened.

Comment: Since you're script is after the `#starbase` div, it'll only execute after it is created, in other words [your scripts works](https://jsfiddle.net/o7ruc9p4/1/) the way you want ti

Comment: I am sorry @TJ, maybe you misunderstood. I would like the render function to fire after the jQuery document ready event has fired. Right now I believe since it is an in place function it will fire at the moment it is encountered (which I think is BEFORE jQuery document ready). Please correct me if I am mistaken in that assumption.

Comment: Your script is at the very bottom of document, just before end of `</body>` , which means all the DOM is ready. There is no practical difference in putting it inside a ready handler. If your `<script>` was in say for example inside `<head>` then DOM ready event will   be useful

Comment: Hi @TJ, I would beg to differ. If I put this inside my render function alert("The status is " + document.readyState );, it says the status is "loading". If DOM ready has already fired, it should say "complete" right?

Comment: My point is that, since your `<script>` tag is at the end of `<body>` tag, when your script runs, all the elements are already created and it'll work fine, so there is no need of jquery dom ready event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add on the ready event the constructor call. See the example below:

```
(function($){

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#starbase"), 

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
        this.render(); 
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append('<div id="starship"></div>');
    }
});

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var listView = new ListView();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you please explain what was the issue with OP's code and how your code fixes it...

Comment: The question was: "How to render Backbone.js view AFTER jQuery document ready has fired?". The original code might work, but is not using the ready event.
This is what the code does.
Is there a reason why you have downvoted the answer?

Comment: That is your assumption. I requested to clarify your answer because I believe by dumping some code as an answer with no explanation (such answers are not encouraged anyway), it made the OP think that his code actually doesn't work, while the fact is that it does. And it seems like misleading a poor guy for reputation.